# What is the easiest way to privately distribute a jar and resolve it's dependencies?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I am an Android developer and my use case is very basic. I have a java library. I want to share the jar with my teammates as a re-usable piece of functionality.

So far I have tried,

Building a .jar from ./gradlew jar by following this guide. But when I include the same jar in Android Studio the jar's dependencies are not resolved.

I can't publish it on bintray or maven central. So I used maven-publish gradle plugin to publishToLocal by following these steps. This didn't help either. In fact, this didn't publish anything at all.

I used gradle shadow jar plugin. It made the jar "fat" i.e. increase the size from 25KB to 3MB.

All I want is to share a jar within my team. And also the transitive dependencies to be resolved.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

To have the dependencies resolved you need a POM file, which needs to be hosted on a maven repository.

On this blog post it's explained how to do it using bitbucket as your private maven: https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/02/05/wagongit/

The TL;DR from the post is:

Add this script to the module gradle:

```
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JeroenMols/GitAsMaven/master/publish-bitbucket.gradle'
```

Add these data to project gradle.properties

```
ARTIFACT_VERSION=<version_here>
ARTIFACT_NAME=<libraryname_here>
ARTIFACT_PACKAGE=<packagename_here>
ARTIFACT_PACKAGING=jar //You could also use aar

COMPANY=<bitbucket_team_company_here> //Username if not part of team
REPOSITORY_NAME=<bitbucket_reponame_here>
```

Add these data to your computer global gradle.properties (on linux it's on `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` (on mac/windows you'll have to figure out yourself)

```
USERNAME=<username_here>
PASSWORD=<password_here>
```

Execute `./gradlew uploadArchives` to send it to the private maven.

Add the new repo on your other project:

```
    maven {
        credentials {
            username USERNAME
            password PASSWORD
        }
        url "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/<your user name>/<the repo name>/raw/releases/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) or create a new module .aar

Comment: Jitpack needs github. Also, it needs you to authorise to be able to read your github repos. I don't want Jitpack to access to all my repos.